# Javascript doesn't validate

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript http://pastebin.com/Lt4HYtaE

and when I submit my form I the validator doesn't work.

I use http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/ his validator form, but it doesn't validator and dosen't output error messages.

I have tried several JavaScript code checkers, and it said `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` on line 49, but I don't understand that error text.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You have one } too much.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem becomes much clearer if you indent your code differently:

```
var validator = new FormValidator(
    'form', 
    [
        { /* ... */ }
    ], 
    function(errors, event) {
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            var errorString = '';

            for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
                errorString += errors[i].message + '<br />';
            }

            el.innerHTML = errorString;
        }      
    }
});
^
```

See the last line with `}`? What should it match? Get rid of it, so the last line will just be `);` matching `FormValidator(/* code */);` instead of `FormValidator(/* code */});`.